# Allow SQL host connection from container with network internal only

Tags: sql-server, docker, docker-compose, docker-network

I have two containers on Docker connected with a custom bridged network with internal flag true (to prevent internet access from/to containers), only the apigwt container (haproxy) has also default bridge network linked to allow inbound/outbound traffic.

I need to allow only SQL connection to SQL Server on the host machine.

SQL Server on the host runs on localhost:1433 (port allowed in firewall rules).

When I try to connect from inside docker container authapi, if the internal network flag is true, I get a SQL connection error, if I try to set it false, thanks to `extra_host` configuration (with `<SERVER_NAME>:<HOST_IP>` right valued), all works fine...and it is obvious.

My question is: can I allow only traffic from container to SQL host only and vice-versa with internal network flag true?

On the other and, is it possible to block all traffic except something (1433 from/to host) in a non internal docker network?

Thanks

Here is my docker compose file

```
name: testproject
services:
  authapi:
    build:
      context: ***\testproject
      dockerfile: AuthApi/Dockerfile
    container_name: authapi
    environment:
      ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: Development
    **extra_hosts:
      - <SERVER_NAME>:<HOST_IP>**
    image: authapi
    networks:
      haproxynet: null
    ports:
      - mode: ingress
        target: 80
        protocol: tcp
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming/Microsoft/UserSecrets
        target: /root/.microsoft/usersecrets
        read_only: true
        bind:
          create_host_path: true
  haproxy:
    build:
      context: ***\testproject
      dockerfile: HaProxy/Dockerfile
    container_name: haproxy
    environment:
      ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: Development
    image: haproxy
    networks:
      default: null
      haproxynet: null
    ports:
      - mode: ingress
        target: 80
        protocol: tcp
      - mode: ingress
        target: 80
        published: "80"
        protocol: tcp
      - mode: ingress
        target: 8404
        published: "8404"
        protocol: tcp
    restart: always
  
networks:
  default:
    name: testproject_default
  haproxynet:
    name: testproject_haproxynet
    driver: bridge
    **internal: true #if true SQL connection to host machine fails, if false works**
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you can also move the database into a container, you can't have it work the way you want to.

Docker doesn't have any firewalling capabilities.  The only networking options at the container perimeter are whether a container accepts inbound connections from outside of Docker (`ports:`) and whether the container can make outbound connections (`internal:`).  If you can make outbound connections (`internal: false`) then you can make connections to anywhere; Docker doesn't have any controls other than whether outbound NAT is enabled at all.

Since the database isn't part of your Compose setup, you need to allow outbound connections to connect to it, and once you've allowed that arbitrary outbound connections are possible.

The easiest answer is probably to move the database into a container.  This will let you get rid of the `extra_hosts:` settings as well.  If the database is in a container, then you can use normal inter-container networking to reach it, and there's no requirement to "leave Docker" to reach the database.